# Is there a way to make a hexagonal jbutton in java? And if so, can I have an example, and if there isn't is there an alternative method

Tags: java, button

I have assigned myself the task of making the board game HEX and I am not sure how to make the backing for the board, I am currently thinking about using JButtons; however, I do not know how to make a hexagonal Jbutton and I am struggling finding out how. I am still new to java so please talk like you're teaching a four year old how to code. 
Many thanks.

UPDATE:
I have tried using buttons with a hexagonal picture implemented this does not support the tiling feature of HEX.

Comment: @user3659052 would that not prevent me from tiling the buttons to make the board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use an Image for your `JButton`. So you create an image with a hexagon and use it for your button:

```
ImageIcon yourImage = new ImageIcon("pathToYourImage");
//Clean the button
yourButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
yourButton.setFocusPainted(false);
yourButton.setBorderPainted(false);
//Set the image
yourButton.setIcon(yourImage); //or new JButton(yourImage);
```

Comment: But you wouldn't be able to tile these like the OP would presumably want to if they are implementing [Hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_%28board_game%29). They'd still be rectangular in area, just with a hexagon drawn on them.

Comment: Yea thats the problem I am having :/